# Check if date isDSTShifted

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to see if a date is [DST shifted](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-dst-shifted/), and I can make it work without telling Moment.js which timezone I am in, thus it will choose my local timezone, but I would like to tell Moment.js which timezone the date is in, but I can not seem to make it work.
Any ideas?

```js
moment.tz.add(['America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0']);


document.write(moment('2014-03-31T02:00:00+02:00', moment.ISO_8601).isDSTShifted());

document.write('<br><br>');

document.write(moment('2014-03-31T02:30:00+02:00').isDSTShifted());

document.write('<br><br>');

document.write(moment.tz('2013-03-10 02:30:00', 'America/New_York').isDSTShifted());

document.write('<br><br>');

// I think this only works because I am in America/New_York
document.write(moment('2013-03-10 2:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').isDSTShifted());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.2.2/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.  I logged it [here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/131).