# Moment Timezone: UTC offset difference

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I use the `moment-timezone v.0.5.3-2016c` library to calculate the UTC offset for a timezone:

```
var z = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
z.utcOffset(); // -420 mins or -7 hours

// check if DST is shifted
z.isDSTShifted(); // false
```

But here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones the UTC offset for the `America/Los_Angeles` is -8 hours.

Moment uses the tzdb v.2016c and the wikipedia article too.

Well, why there are two different results here? And which result is right?

P.S.: there is the same difference for `America/Kentucky/Monticello` and `Europe/Tiraspol`, as well.

Comment: `-7` is the correct answer at the present time (29 April 2016). The question is why the Moment `.isDSTOffset()` routine doesn't know that. I think it has something to do with how Moment gets possession of the Date value; if it comes from a native Date object, it may not be able to tell.

Comment: [See this bug report.](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/131)

Comment: [Also this older SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063400/check-if-date-isdstshifted)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarifications! This `moment("20160101").tz("America/Los_Angeles").utcOffset()` works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the moment creation function, `moment()` without any arguments returns the *current* moment in time.  Since time zone offsets vary depending on what date and time they are attached to, your results will vary depending on when you call this function.

If you want to know whether or not the time is daylight saving time or not, use `isDST`.  The `isDSTShifted` function is for dealing with invalid local times, not checking DST.  It probably could have been named better.

Answer (score 2):

The USA is currently in DST (Daylight Savings Time). Therefore, I'd use the `UTC DST Offset` column, which shows `-07:00`.

Comment: The question is about why the Moment `.isDSTOffset()` function is returning `false`, when the time zone clearly *is* in DST currently.

Comment: Ah... sorry. I misread what the problem really was. It looks like it's a bug then.